# Bed Bath and Beyond: Q1 or Q2

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, stock-analysis, yahoo-finance

Why do the news releases say that Bed Bath and Beyond released its Q1 earnings. Shouldn't it be Q2 earnings right now? On Yahoo finance, it says the recently released report was Q2 but BBBY says that it is Q1?

Answer (score 2):

Bed Bath and Beyond's Fiscal year is March-February, so March-May is their "first quarter".  It's common to take a month or so to put together quarterly reports, so you won't see "2Q" reports for companies that use Jan-Dec as their fiscal year until early August.

The only reference I've found to "2Q2018" on yahoo is the x-axis of their graphs. I suspect that this is just a bug in their charts and they don't adapt to staggered fiscal years well.

Comment: shouldn't it be fiscal year 2019 ? So it's the 1st quarter of 2019 ?

Answer (score 2):

Fiscal periods vary wildly between companies, the Bed Bath and Beyond releases seem consistent, so likely Yahoo is incorrect.

From [Bed Bath & Beyond's site](http://bedbathandbeyond.gcs-web.com/news-releases/news-release-details/bed-bath-beyond-inc-reports-results-fiscal-2017-fourth-quarter):

> UNION, N.J., April 11, 2018 /PRNewswire/ -- Bed Bath & Beyond Inc.
>   (NASDAQ: BBBY) today reported financial results for the fiscal fourth
>   quarter (14 weeks) and full year (53 weeks) ended March 3, 2018

Their fiscal year seems to end early March, so a Q1 end in May/early June, plus some time to shore up reports makes sense.

Edit: I only see references to Q1 from recent stories on [Yahoo! Finance for BB&B](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/bbby/), so not sure where the error is.